# Filtering elements by multiple data- values simultaneously

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

To get `li` elements with its `data-param1` attribute equal to `variable1` I do:

```
$( 'li[data-param1=' + variable1 +']' )
```

But how to further filter those `li` elements with a `data-param2` attribute? It would be something like:

```
$( 'li[data-param1=' + variable1 +'][data-param2=' + variable2 +']'' )
```

Except this doesn't work.

Comment: It [works here](http://jsfiddle.net/4s08cfm9/).. although you need to remove that extra single quote `'` at the end there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just have an extra `'` at the end because when I fix that, it works just fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/jfsanvkh/